# Binding method to button - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Python Code:

```
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')
    def btn(self):
        print('Button Pressed')
```

kv code:

```
MDScreen:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:'Submit'
        on_press: root.btn()
```

On pressing the Button, I'm receiving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'MDScreen' object has no attribute 'btn'
```

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I am using `kivymd` which is a fork of `kivy` and works almost the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on_press: root.btn()

As the error says, `root` evaluates to your `MdScreen` instance, the root of the kv rule. You want `app.btn()`.

> BTW, I am using kivymd which is a fork of kivy and works almost the same way.

KivyMD is not a fork of Kivy, it's a module that depends on Kivy.